# Changing url using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

**Hello there**

I am developing a jQuery plugin that loads files through ajax. When user clicks on a button which is:

```
<button class='btn btn-info' data-load="ajax" data-file="ajax/login.html" >Login</button>
```

When user clicks on button it generates following url:

```
http://localhost//plugins/ajaxLoad/index.html#ajax/Login
```

I want to change it to

```
http://localhost//plugins/ajaxLoad/index.html/ajax/Login
```

My javascript is:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.ajaxLoad = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        fileUrl : 'null',
        loadOn : '.em'

    }, options);
    $('[data-load="ajax"]').each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var file = $(this).attr('data-file');
            var loadOn = $(this).attr('data-load-on');
            var permission = $(this).attr("data-ask-permission");
            settings.fileUrl = file;
            settings.loadOn = loadOn;
            if (permission == 'yes') {
                var ask = confirm("Do you want to load file");
                if (ask == true) {
                    $.fn.loadFile();
                }
            }else {
                $.fn.loadFile();
            }
        });
    });
    $.fn.loadFile = function () {
        // setting location;
        var a = settings.fileUrl.split(".");
        location.hash = a[0];
        $.post(settings.fileUrl, function(response) {
            $(settings.loadOn).html(response);
        });
    }
}
}(jQuery))
```

Can anyone tell me how to change url in jquery and Javascript.

Comment: When i use **location.hash** feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another attribute title to button

```
<button data-title="login" class='btn btn-info' data-load="ajax" data-file="ajax/login.html" >Login</button>
```

In Js (after $(this).click line):

```
var title = $(this).attr('data-title');
settings.title = title
```

Just replace

```
location.hash = a[0];
```

With

```
history.pushState('','',"?"+settings.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use history.pushstate() to do this.

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Have a look at this article on MDN for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

This article gives some nice jQuery examples. 
https://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery

Comment: How can is remove the data which i've written using push state.

Comment: Not sure I follow your question, this just changes the URL, whilst keeping you on the same page.

Comment: Let i have a url **wapgee.com/index.php** i changed it to **wapgee.com/index.php/game/12** now i want to change it as deafult **wapgee.com/index.php**. How can i achieve this using push state

Comment: history.pushState({},'','index.php');

Comment: What is second parameter of pushState.

Comment: Title, but it's ignored, just put an empty string in for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the hash with a blank using **.replace()**

Example .

```
settings.fileUrl.replace('.' , ' ');

Updated above also
```

UPDATE :

Don't hash the URL

Example :

```
 $.fn.loadFile = function () {
        // setting location;
        var a = settings.fileUrl.replace("." , "/");
        location.href = a;
        $.post(settings.fileUrl, function(response) {
            $(settings.loadOn).html(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `#` in `settings.fileURL`. The hash is coming from the assignment to `location.hash`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
location.hash = a[0];
```

to:

```
location.pathname += '/' + a[0];
```

Comment: It works but the page redirects and it shows **404 NOT FOUND** error message.

Comment: If you want to change the URL without actually redirecting, you probably need to use the History API, as in @DavidBradshaw's answer.

Comment: Yeah DavidBradshaw's answer helped me